# Curl outputting to screen or not saving as file

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $dl_destination);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
$cError = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This seems to work fine in one location in the script but not another. In the problem area it will output the file contents to the screen and save the file. Without CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  it will save the file and output the contents to the screen. If add CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER as I've read should work, it does not save the file and instead puts the contents into $curlResult. I just need it to save the file without outputting to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the data using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and save it in a variable. 
Now, use `file_put_contents` to write data to a file.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
$cError = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(empty($cError)){
    if(file_put_contents($dl_destination,$curlResult)){
        echo "Data written to file successfully";
    }else{
        die("Could not write to file.");
    }
}else{
    die("Curl Error: " .$cError);
}
```